# Как передать в reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources источник в виде базы данных?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, reporting-services, reportviewer, report

Всем привет!

Ситуация такая: есть отчет Report.rdl, созданный в "Построитель отчетов 3.0". В него внедрен источник данных в виде подключения к базе данных (Microsoft SQL server, база данных - DataBase1). Так же в этом отчете есть наборы данных (Set1, Set2 и т.д.), которые получают всю информацию из источника данных.
Сам по себе отчет работает отлично.

Задача: с помощью ReportViewer в Visual Studio 2017 отобразить отчет.

Моя проблема в том что, при передаче источника данных в отчет, конструктор требует указывать имя набора данных и передает ему параметр типа ReportDataSource (грубо говоря - таблицу), например:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Set1", dt));
```

где dt, например:

```
//подключение к базе DataBase1 и все такое
cmd.CommandText = "Select top (10) id from [Table1]";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
```

Мне же необходимо передать всю базу, поскольку мои наборы данных сами из нее извлекают всю информацию.
Тело набора данных Set1:

```
select top (10) id as ID from [Table1]
```

Псевдокод желаемого результата, так сказать:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datebase1);
```

Будьте добры, подскажите, как мне реализовать это?

Comment: Я немного продвинулась в своем вопросе. Можно в качестве параметра передать строку подключения к базе.  `new ReportParameter("Base", "Строка подключения к базе данных") `. Только вот теперь надо заставить отчет использовать этот параметр :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проведя не один десяток исследований, я пришла к выводу, что так сделать нельзя. 
Необходимо частично копировать содержимое отчета в код.

Например:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "Select top (10) id from [Table1]";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
ReportDataSource rprtDTSource = new ReportDataSource();
rprtDTSource.Name = "Org";
rprtDTSource.Value = dt;                                
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rprtDTSource);
```

Где "Select top (10) id from [Table1]" - запрос набора данных Org из отчета